# HttpWebRequest not returning response stream when cache hit, and AllowAutoRedirect == false

Tags: .net, caching, httpwebrequest

I have an HttpWebRequest that I've set the CachePolicy to CacheIfAvailable, and I've set AllowAutoRedirect to false.
Now when there is a cache hit, the HttpWebResponse.Status == NotModified, and there is no response stream.  I need to know what the cached response is!

If I set the CachePolicy to BypassCache it works just fine.  But I need to cache these results.

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve the cached response in the case of a cache hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is that I was setting HttpWebRequest.IfModifiedSince (to itself).  Yes, the getter for that property is set to always return DateTime.Now, until it is explicitly set.  So:
request.IfModifiedSince = request.IfModifiedSince;
is not a safe no-op.  It actually sets a flag saying to actually send the If-Modified-Since HTTP header, which was causing my grief.